Refresh left side of shuttle only using cascading Parent item
I have a shuttle on a page, with a parent LOV.
Parent LOV is used to define the values for the Left side of the shuttle.
However, when I switch the values in LOV, and the shuttle refreshes, I loose values on the Right side of a shuttle!
I tried to use dynamic action, instead of LOV, to refresh the left side of the shuttle, using the ID of a Left side, but it does not work.
The shuttle refreshes completely (both sides), and data on the Right side is being lost
Is there any solution to refresh only Left side of the shuttle, please?
enter image description here

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.
